# Function would not return 0, cant find error in logic

Tags: c, function, pointers, while-loop, return

I am not sure why the following code isnt working.

I try to use gcc to compile it `gcc -Wall -o test test.c`, it gives me warning message: control reaches end of non void function.

But I couldn't find the error so I tried to compile it ignoring the warning messages, and tested the program out using `./test 1234321` after compiling it using `gcc -o test ispalidrome.c`

But instead of returning 0 (that it should to my understanding because it didn't trigger any of the if statements to return 1), it returned a random value, 46, 52, 84 etc.

The main logic behind the program is exactly as required, I just can't tell why it isn't exiting properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr,  "Usage: %s \"string\"", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        int i = 0;
        while( '\0' != argv[1][i] ) i++;
        char *start=argv[1];
        char *end=&start[i-1];

        while (start<end){
            if (*start != *end){
                break;
                return 1;
            }
            printf("%c is the same as %c\n",*start, *end);
            start =start+1;
            end=end-1; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `return 0;` before the last `}`.

Comment: Note that your code will never return 1, because the line before `return 1;` is `break;` which jumps to just after the loop.

Comment: @immibis Well it *will* `return 1` if `argc != 2`. But yes, that spot is most likely a mistake.

Comment: specify `std=c99` then you don't need a `return 0` at the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `main` function is very obviously missing a `return 0` at the end.

The random value it is returning is whatever happens to be in the return value register (`eax` on x86) when `main` returned.

Never turn off `-Wall`, and never ignore the warnings. They are your friend.

---

As [Jim Balter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544557/jim-balter) and [Lưu Vĩnh Phúc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006084/function-would-not-return-0-cant-find-error-in-logic/22006124?noredirect=1#comment33354694_22006084) mentioned, the [`return 0` is optional in C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional).

Comment: Many warnings are unnecessary. Always using `-Wall` might be a good idea for finding issues in production code, but for education it is likely to just add confusion.

Comment: @immibis I disagree. `-Wall -Werror` sets good habits for beginners. I wish `-Wall` were the default.

Comment: I also disagree.  The warnings may not always be important to beginners, but they are often the cause of subtle programming flaws that will cripple complex programs.

Comment: I did say they should be turned on when making complex programs (which is what I meant by production code). But it is usually better to learn from things not working than to learn from compiler warnings.

Comment: @immibis Still disagree, but to each his own. It doesn't really matter because the OP had a clear error message and it still didn't help.

Comment: `return 0` isn't required in C99 or later.

Comment: @JimBalter Woah, what? Citation, please.

Comment: No, you take the 10 seconds to google it if your knowledge of C is that poor.

Comment: @JimBalter I was already googling it. I can honestly say I feel foolish for not knowing that (I work strictly in a C89 environment), but I'm mostly surprised they introduced such a feature.

Comment: "They" adopted it from the 1998 C++ standard, so this probably originates from Stroustrup.

Comment: Such an obvious problem! I cant believe I looked at this thing for an hour and wasnt able to find it! thank you guys~

Comment: @NickGong Not a problem. And some of us learned something from it.

Answer (score 1):

You're method declaration specifies that it returns an `int`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
```

You do correctly return an int at the end of your if block when you do

```
return 1;
```

but at the end of your else block there is no int returned.  You can return any integer, but 0 is common for programs that naturally terminate, or you can specify a different integers to specify different exit situations.

Answer (score 1):

Add line return 0 at the end of code. It will return proper value.