# #including <alsa/asoundlib.h> and <sys/time.h> results in multiple definition conflict

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, x86, c99, alsa

Here is the minimal C program to reproduce:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main( void )
{
}
```

This will compile with `gcc -c -o timealsa.o timealsa.c`, but if you include the `-std=c99` switch, you get a redefinition error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/time.h:28:0,
                 from timealsa.c:3:
/usr/include/bits/time.h:30:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct timeval’
 struct timeval
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h:49:0,
                 from timealsa.c:2:
/usr/include/alsa/global.h:138:8: note: originally defined here
 struct timeval {
        ^
```

How can I resolve this conflict while still using `-std=c99`?

Comment: You should use the minimum standard of main which is **int main(void){return 0;}**

Comment: Yes, you're right (but that's one more line!)

Comment: @Michi the `return 0` is implicit if not present in _C99_ (Whcih this question is tagged with). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional . The  void is a problem though

Comment: Since the question is focused on the c99 standard I will make it more compliant.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I found there that **Returning 0 from main is in C99 § 5.1.2.2.3**

Comment: Indeed `reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0`, but we *are* submarining here into an unrelated issue :)

Comment: There was about **return 0** and not about **0** or something else.

Comment: In C99 it is implicit, so if you don't put `return 0` it is implied. This isn't the case for C89/C90 .

Comment: And it's a bad idea, IMHO, because `main()` shouldn't be "special". But indeed, this is completely unrelated here. And btw, `int main(void)` is fine, too.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Sir, sorry now I understood your point :)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question suggests you are using GLIBC's `time.h` there is a way to avoid this by telling it not to define `timeval`. Include `asoundlib.h` first then define `_STRUCT_TIMEVAL`. The one defined in `asoundlib.h` will be the one that gets used.

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#ifndef _STRUCT_TIMEVAL
#  define _STRUCT_TIMEVAL
#endif
#include <sys/time.h>

int main( void )
{
}
```

Comment: This works - so what does `std=c99` bring to the table that makes us then need to explicitly disable sys/time's definition of timeval?

Comment: @Lombard it enforces standards compliance, so redefinitions are illegal. Try `std=c89`, will give you the same result.

Comment: @Lombard : I have made a small alteration to the code to only define _STRUCT_TIMEVAL if it isn't already defined. There are some warning options like `-Wall` that may pick up the redefinition of the define as a problem.

Comment: GCC doesn't come with a time.h. You probably mean glibc. Depending on the target system, GCC can use any of a number of libc implementations.

Answer (score 2):

With C99 and later you can't have duplicate definitions of the same struct. The problem is that `alsa/asoundlib.h` includes `alsa/global.h` which contains this code:

```
/* for timeval and timespec */
#include <time.h>

...

#ifdef __GLIBC__
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_SOURCE)
struct timeval {
        time_t          tv_sec;         /* seconds */
        long            tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
};

struct timespec {
        time_t          tv_sec;         /* seconds */
        long            tv_nsec;        /* nanoseconds */
};
#endif
#endif
```

So the Michael Petch's solution won't work - by the time you've included `alsa/asoundlib.h` it is already too late. The proper solution is to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` (`_POSIX_SOURCE` is obsolete). There's more information about these macros [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).

For example you could try `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`. However, if you do that you'll get errors like this:

```
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/time.h:110:20: error: field ‘it_interval’ has incomplete type
     struct timeval it_interval;
                    ^
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/time.h:112:20: error: field ‘it_value’ has incomplete type
     struct timeval it_value;
                    ^
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/time.h:138:61: error: array type has incomplete element type
 extern int utimes (const char *__file, const struct timeval __tvp[2])
                                                             ^
```

This is all a big mess of old C code and macro madness. The only way I got it to work was to give up and use `-std=gnu11`.