# C File Input/Output on Windows

Tags: c, file-io

First of all, this is my fist stack overflow question, so forgive me if I format this wrong.

I am a beginner at C, and I am up to a point in my book on File i/o. The following code, which is supposed to print the lines to test.txt, doesn't create a new txt file or... do anything.

I am running Code Blocks 16.01 on Windows. Is this code designed for another OS?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
    fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Ok, so removing the slash makes it work. In the original code, it is 'fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "W+");'
Shouldn't this create the file in folder tmp?

Comment: `main()` --> `int main (void)`...BTW what's the problem?

Comment: It isn't creating test.txt

Comment: Where do you expect that the file is created?

Comment: @LPs `main()` should also return value to OS.

Comment: @rootTraveller Not really. Take a look [at this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional)

Comment: it still isn't creating the .txt file

Comment: Windows doesn't use forward slashes between path components.

Comment: @user3386109 so how would the new code be?

Comment: @user3386109: actually you *can* use forward slashes in paths, even on Windows.

Comment: @user7005993: you probably want something like: `fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");` to create the file in your current working directory.

Comment: @rootTraveller I used the proper file path with /  and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @user7005993 that's the beauty if Linux  :)

Comment: @rootTraveller yes, but it would be nice to have windows for other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double `//` in windows for navigate through directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    /* 
       file path in windows should be like this= C:\\users\\r.maurya\\Desktop\\Downloads\\file.txt 
    */
    fp = fopen("C:\\users\\r.maurya\\Desktop\\Downloads\\file.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
    fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);
return 0;//Optional, On success of program 
}
```

Comment: Note that the escaped backslash is not necessary - you can just use the standard `/`, which is interpreteted in the same way on Windows and is somewhat more portable.

Comment: I suggest you try it - it does actually work with a Windows path.

Comment: @PaulR yaa Sure :)

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the front-slash from the file name. You seem to be doing everything properly, the slash might be the problem. If not, let us know.

Edit: When I wrote my comment your fopen used "/test.txt" and not "/temp/test.txt", do you have the "temp" folder created in the directory the application is running from? If not, try creating it. Or remove it altogether and try creating the text file within the directory the application is running from.