# Is it essential to use a return 0 statement when we use int main() in c?

Tags: c

What will happen if we don't use it? will the compiler automatically add it like it does in C++?

Comment: @FredLarson, I don't think that this is the correct duplicate. Thie one there asks about the return *type*. This one here asks if the `return` statement is really necesary.

Comment: @JensGustedt: It's thoroughly covered in the answers. For example, "It's also worth noting that in C++, int main() can be left without a return value at which point it defaults to returning 0. This is also true with a C99 program."

Comment: @FredLarson, a better duplicate would have been https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional, but I was not fast enough you guys closed it already.

Comment: Perfectly valid question.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits: That's usually a *bad* idea where C is concerned; there are too many ways to write code that *looks* like it works correctly, but contains all kinds of nasty time bombs waiting for the right moment to blow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will return `0` automatically in C99-compliant compilers (and later). In pre-C99 compilers the return value is undefined in such cases.

In other words, in *modern* C you don't need an explicit `return 0` at the end of `main`.

Comment: While this is technically true, enough compilers still default to C89 mode, or just plain don't implement C99 at all, that I think omitting the `return 0` in C is still a bad idea.