# printing strong number ( c Programming)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

**Basci Program** My logic is not working properly to "find the strong number" of given range. Nothing is printing even after giving range of number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,r,sum,fact,limit,i;
     printf("Enter the limit to find strong numbers");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    for(n=1;i<=limit;n++)
    {
        sum=0;
        while(n>0)
        {
            r=n%10;
            fact=1;
            for(i=r;i>=1;i--)
            {
                fact = fact*i;
            }
            sum = sum+fact;
            n=n/10;
         }
         if(n == sum)
         printf("%d is a strong number\n", n);
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and find where you are doing something wrong.

Comment: At first glance: a typo: `for(n=1;i<=limit;n++)` you should check `n<=limit`

Comment: ...but then, you are modifying `n` in the inner loop. Seems you have some problems to sort out.

Comment: After the `while(n>0)` loop, `n` will be zero. How can `n` then ever be equal to `sum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You are missing a `return 0` statement at the end of the program for
   the `main` function *(though this is not required by the C99 and above standards as said in the comments)*
2. You are missing the `main` function end brace
3. As said in the comments, your for loop condition is wrong `for(n=1;i<=limit;n++)` it should compare `n` instead of `i` like
   such `for(n=1;n<=limit;n++)`
4. You are overwriting the n number counter here `n=n/10;`. Instead you should you another variable to break down the number into digits
   like such before the `while` loop `int num = n;`
5. Lastly, it would be useful to print if a number is not a strong number with an else clause in the last `if` statement like such `else printf("%d is not a strong number", n);`

Here is the correct program:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                         
int main()                                                 
{                                                          
    int n, r, sum, fact, limit, i;                         

    printf("Enter the limit to find strong numbers");      

    scanf("%d", &limit);                                   

    for (n = 1; n <= limit; n++) // Point 3
    {                                                      
        sum = 0;                                           

        int num = n; // Point 4

        while (num > 0)                                    
        {                                                  
            r = num % 10;                                  

            fact = 1;                                      

            for (i = r; i >= 1; i--)                       

            {                                              
                fact = fact * i;                           
            }                                              

            sum = sum + fact;                              

            num = num / 10;                                
        }                                                  

        if (n == sum) printf("%d is a strong number\n", n);
        else printf("%d is not a strong number\n", n); // Point 5
    }                                                      

    return 0; // Point 1
} // Point 2
```

Comment: Regarding point 1, since the C99 standard if the `main` function misses an explicit `return` statement or `exit` call, the C compiler adds an implicit `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good point. I didn't know that. Could you append the section in the standard where is says that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional

Comment: @john well corrected code. Its working now. I only need the list of strong number in the given range. Hence I removed the else statement // Point 5.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should declare variables in the minimal scope where they are used. Otherwise it is difficult to read code.

Within this statement

```
for(n=1;i<=limit;n++)
        ^^^^^^^^
```

there is a typo. The variable `i` is not initialized. You have to write

```
for ( n=1; n <= limit; n++ )
```

However in the next loop the variable `n` is being changed.

```
while(n>0)
{
    //...
    n=n/10;
 }
```

You need to use another variable in this loop. For example before the loop you could write

```
int value = n;
while ( value > 0 )
{
    //...
}
```

This loop

```
for(i=r;i>=1;i--)
```

can have one iteration less

```
for(i=r;i > 1;i--)
```

Also it is better to use the type `unsigned int` instead of the type `int`. Otherwise the user can enter a negative number.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "Enter the limit to find strong numbers: " );
    unsigned int n = 0;

    scanf( "%u", &n );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        unsigned int value = i + 1;

        unsigned int sum = 0;

        do
        {
            unsigned int f = 1;
            for ( unsigned int digit = value % 10; digit > 1; digit-- )
            {
                f *= digit;
            }

            sum += f;
        } while ( value /= 10 );

        if ( i + 1 == sum )
        {
            printf( "%u is a strong number.\n", i + 1 );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the limit to find strong numbers: 145
1 is a strong number.
2 is a strong number.
145 is a strong number.
```