# Inputting a space seperated 2-D array

Tags: c, gcc, multidimensional-array, runtime-error

I was recently working on 2-D arrays in C. My code looks something like this -

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int A[3][3];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The input I gave was -

2 1 3

1 3 2

1 2 3

But I don't know why the **C(GCC 6.3)** compiler tends to throw a **run-time error**. The code seems to work fine and matrix A shows everything perfectly while display.

Comment: Do you have an exact error message to show?

Comment: While running on the codechef platform, it says NZEC (Runtime Error)

Comment: `void main()` <<-- main should return int.

Comment: Did you do any basic searches? Searching for "codechef nzec" gives [Why do I get an NZEC?](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/why-do-i-get-an-nzec/1775) as the first hit.

Comment: Ya ! Thanks a lot kaylum. Changing main's return type worked fantastic !

Answer (score 0):

The runtime error, **NZEC** stands for Non Zero Exit Code.

Your program should `return 0` in order to indicate that it ran successfully.

But it does not return anything because you have used `void main()`.

**Solution:**

1. Change `void main()` to `int main()`
2. Add a `return 0;` at the end of `main` ([optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional))

Comment: @EricPostpischil *Re: "Unless you know that OP’s C implementation behaves differently"*. I know it because he used `void main`, which is not Standard C.