# Why does my function always return 0 instead of returning the sum result?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I just started learning C++, now I'm making a simple array sum function.

Why is my code output always 0? Does it mean that my function returns `"0"`?

If I put `cout` in the function, it shows the right sum result.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ArraySum(int arr[], int size){
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0 ; i<size; i++){
      cin >> arr[i];
      sum +=arr[i];
  }   
  return sum;
}
   
int main()
{
    int n, sum;
      cin >>n;
   int arr[n];
     ArraySum(arr, n);
   cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ArraySum(arr, n);` -> `sum = ArraySum(arr, n);`. Trying to print the value of an uninitialized variable is [*Undefined Behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `int arr[n];` is invalid in C++. It's just an extension in some compilers. Use `std::vector` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the return value to the `sum` when it is returned.

You have 2 options:

- pass a pointer to the `sum`, and dereference it inside `ArraySum()`
- assign the value that is returned by `ArraySum()` to the `sum` int.

Comment: i use the second option you gave because i haven't learned pointer. it works perfectly.
thanks for the answer, its very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign `ArraySum()`'s return value to `main()`'s `sum`. As a result, `main()`'s `sum` is still uninitialized when you print it.

Change this:

```
ArraySum(arr, n);
```

to this:

```
sum = ArraySum(arr, n);
```

As a side note, you should know that this is not actually valid, standard C++:

```
int arr[n];
```

This is a "variable-length array" ("VLA" for short.) This works on some C++ compilers because they support VLAs as an extension. But relying on compiler-specific extensions is not recommended if you want your code to be portable to any other C++ compiler.

Use `std::vector` instead. This also has the benefit of not needing to manually keep track of the size. `vector` knows its own size.

So, use this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Note the '&' here. That means a reference of the vector is passed,
// not a copy, so the original vector defined in main() is used when
// assigning the values we read with `cin`.
int ArraySum(std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
   
int main()
{
    int n;
    int sum;

    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    sum = ArraySum(arr);
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

(Also note that there is no need to `return 0` at the end of `main()`. It happens automatically. Keep in mind that *this is only true for `main()`*. No other function that returns a value is allowed to omit the `return` statement. `main()` is a special case in this regard. But it doesn't hurt to `return 0` anyway though. It's up to preference.)

Comment: "*Also note that in C++, **unlike C**, there is no need to return 0 at the end of main(). It happens automatically.*" - Actually, you can [omit `return 0` since C99 as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4138846/8423261).

Comment: @Ruks Right. Thanks!